# Checking Servers with Motor(Mongodb & Tornado)

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, pymongo, tornado-motor

I need to create a function that checks to make sure Mongo servers are running using the ping function. I set up the clients right there (the config file has dictionary with ports numbers)

```
   clientList = []
for value in configuration["mongodbServer"]:
    client = motor.motor_tornado.MotorClient('mongodb://localhost:{}'.format(value))
    clientList.append(client)
```

and then i run this function:

```
class MongoChecker(Checker):

formatter = 'stashboard.formatters.MongoFormatter'
def check(self):
 for x in clientList:
        if x.ping:
            return x.ping
```

and the error i get:

```
 yielded unknown object MotorDatabase(Database(MongoClient([]), 'ping'))\n",
```

I think my issue is that i'm using the ping function wrong. I can't find any other documentation on that or any other kind of feature that would check to see if the servers are still running. If anyone knows of a better way to monitor the status using Motor, i'm open. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, there's no "ping" function. Hence MotorClient thinks you're trying to access the database named "ping". The database named "ping" is shown in the "unknown object" exception. For all MongoDB commands like "ping", just use MotorDatabase's [command method](http://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/motor_database.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorDatabase.command).

Second, Motor is asynchronous. You must use Motor methods in a Tornado coroutine with the "yield" statement. For example:

```
@gen.coroutine
def check():
    try:
        result = yield client.admin.command({'ping': 1})
        print(result)
    except ConnectionFailure as exc:
        print(exc)
```

If you want to test this out synchronously, you can run the IOLoop just long enough for the coroutine to complete:

```
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

import motor.motor_tornado

client = motor.motor_tornado.MotorClient()
IOLoop.current().run_sync(check)
```

For an introduction to Tornado coroutines, see [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/) and the [Tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html).